# Django: Customizing ManyToManyField form options

Tags: python, django

I have a ManyToManyField in a Django template like so: `{{ form.contacts }}`

When rendering the `Contact` objects in a list, Django prints the `__str__` (or `__unicode__`) for each object (the ID).

In my case, I want a more human-friendly display of each object, so instead of rendering each of the objects ID's; I'd like to have the name of the object and just some more data about it.

So, is there any way to customize each of the list items so that I can add divs to the HTML and display other bits of data for each object like you would do in a for loop?

Django render:

```
<li>
    <label for ...>
        <input type='checkbox'...>
        </input>
        'id generated here'
    </label>
</li>
```

What I want:

```
<li>
    <label for ...>
        <input type='checkbox'...>
        </input>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <h3>'contact name here'</h3>
            <h4>'contact id here'</h4>
            <h4>'contact created date here'</h4>
        </div>
# Note that the only difference is the markup here, where I can add in my own tags, as opposed to the ID/slug string that Django rendered
    </label>
 </li>
```

**Update**

models.py for Contacts:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyModel, related_name='contact',
        verbose_name='Parent Company')
    cl_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')
    cl_dt_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date Created')
    cl_slug = models.SlugField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Contact'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cl_slug

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cl_slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contact-detail', kwargs={'cl_slug': self.cl_slug, 'company': self.parent.company})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug_create(self) # Call slug_save method
        super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: post your models file

Comment: @sasuke Updated with the Contacts model. Note that the __str__ is a slug and not id; however, my problem is still the same as before

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with Django for a bit, but from what I recall your issue may be bc m2m relationships are lazy, and that nothing has caused the model to load the other side of the relation, so it's just an id when it arrives at the template. Have you tried enumerating contacts in your controller code or iterating through the set in your template?

Comment: @XingzhouLiu Apologies but I'm unsure what you mean by 'nothing has caused the model to load the other side of the relation' - everything is rendering perfectly fine in the template, except I want to know how to change the styling of the text that Django renders (as shown in the code in my original q)

Comment: I think you can write a loop in the template that loops through the contacts like for contact in form.contacts.all()? Sorry if that was confusing but it doesn't populate the other fields of a m2m relation unless you call  form.contact.all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there any way to customize each of the list items so that I can add divs to the HTML and display other bits of data for each object like you would do in a for loop?

Assuming your view is sending a context variable of all the Contacts like the following.

```
def myview(request, *a, **kw):
    # querying the related objects
    company_model = CompanyModel.objects.get(id=some_id)
    # creating a dictionary containing the queryset that we want based on these related objects.
    data['contacts'] = Contacts.objects.filter(parent__id=company_model.id)
    # You can still pass your form in with this data like so
    data['form'] = MyForm
    # passing that queryset and the form to the template to be displayed.
    return render(request, "path/to/template", data)
```

You should be able to iterate over that queryset in your template like so.

```
# this would go inside your form
{% for contact in contacts %}
    <div>{{ contact.cl_name }}</div>
    <div>{{ contact.cl_slug }}</div> cl_dt_created
    <div>{{ contact.cl_dt_created }}</div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ contact.id }}" name="contact" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this does work perfectly for a list of objects in a view, this method doesn't allow me to iterate over a list of objects for a ManyToMany or ForeignKey field and select these objects as you would on a form.

Comment: ideally, I need something that combines this with iterating over form field options in HTML.

Comment: @jayt I edited my answer to be a little more clear. You can still use this method to select objects in a form (by just adding an input to the for loop.) And the objects that you are passing to the template and iterating over is completely based on the query you make in your view.

Comment: This works really well on the styling side of things, thank you - does this still function in the same way that the normal form would since now the Contacts aren't passed into the template as an attribute of the ModelForm (as no longer have {{ form.contact }} in the template)?

Comment: You do not have to pass your contacts as a form attribute in order to use them in your form. You just have to build the correct HTML. Which boils down to having those `input type='checkbox ..` and the correct query in the view. Both ways are valid, but I think my way is easier to understand.